# resignation under acute mental health episode

Tags: resignation, mental-health

A close relative in the UK resigned from his job while going through an acute mental health episode. Employer accepted his resignation, and he was put on garden leave until this coming Sep 14.
In the meantime, he was hospitalized under the mental health act.
Now he will probably lose the possibility to be on a long-term medical leave. Is this resignation still valid when it was done without full mental capacity?
How to remediate this situation so he doesn't lose income and possibly of going on medical leave or disability benefits.
Please assist as he is the sole breadwinner for his family, wife and 2 kids.

Comment: This is really a legal question, not one of navigating the workplace.

Comment: This is a legal question that stretches multiple disciplines, not just labor law. As such, it *may* have been a good fit at law.se, but they only deal in theoretical cases, not practical advice. A lot is at stake here, so you really need a *lawyer* to help you navigate this, not random internet people.

Comment: The urgency and specificity of the situation requires you to seek out an employment lawyer right away.

Comment: While talking to a lawyer is almost certainly going to be necessary, telling the employer "I spoke rashly while ill and would prefer to be on disability leave until I can recover and then return to this job I love and am good at" is at least worth trying. If they like him and understand what is at stake, they may just fix things up. Sure, if they don't it's possible the legal system can force them to, but there's no harm in trying something less adversarial as a first effort.

Comment: What is an 'acute mental health episode'?

Comment: In the UK, free legal guidance is available from ACAS (specialists in employment law) and Citizens Advice (generalists; experience with the benefits system). https://www.acas.org.uk/contact https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/